# What’s the reading order for Superior Iron Man?

Tags: marvel, suggested-order, iron-man

I want to start reading Superior Iron Man.

What is the ideal reading order for Superior Iron Man?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. What's wrong with starting at Issue #1 and going from there? There's only 9 issues anyway AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

There are nine issues of *Superior Iron Man* and it doesn't have crossovers to other series. So just pick up #1 and read each issue in sequence.

You may have been confused by the "Marvel NOW!" (and "Avengers NOW!") labels. This isn't a crossover, but rather a company-wide branding effort indicating that new comics were being produced for the modern day, often with unusual premises that differed from traditional comics stories (like an evil Iron Man). Don't worry, it's not a crossover name or anything.

Answer (score 1):

The main portions of Superior Iron Man's story is in:

- **Avengers & X-Men: Axis** gives the reasons behind "Superior". This is collected in both trade and Hardcover
- **Superior Iron Man v1: Infamous** collects *Superior Iron Man* #1-5. Available as both trade and Hardcover
- **Superior Iron Man v2: Stark Contrast** collects *Superior Iron Man* #6-9. Available as both trade and Hardcover
- **Avengers: Time Runs Out**: The last appearance of Superior Iron Man before *Secret Wars*. *Avengers* 35-44, *New Avengers* #24-33.

  Collected as either a single large Hardcover or 4 smaller trade/hardcovers:

  - **Avengers: Time Runs Out v1**: *Avengers* #35-37 & *New Avengers* #24-25
  - **Avengers: Time Runs Out v2**: *Avengers* #38-39 & *New Avengers* #26-28
  - **Avengers: Time Runs Out v3**: *Avengers* #40-42 & *New Avengers* #29-30
  - **Avengers: Time Runs Out v4**: *Avengers* #43-44 & *New Avengers* #31-33

> Iron Man seems to be un-superior by the time of Bendis' run in the All-New All-Different Marvel Universe that came after *Secret Wars*.